# Parsing strings that may have different values each time

Tags: ruby

I have the following string:

```
"---\n- :@error: 'Invalid phone number format: ''''.  Please check that your format  for\n    phone number is correct.'\n- :@error: 'Invalid id was sent: '\n- :@error: 'Invalid date format: '\n"
```

I am trying to return only the error messages. So that would be

- `"Invalid phone number format:"`
- `"Please check that your format for phone number is correct."`
- `"Invalid id was sent:"`
- `"Invalid date format:"`

Certain messages that will be returned will be different than the ones above, so I don't think using regex match would be the best method. Any ideas how I can extract only the error messages from this string?

Comment: I do not believe so. It's simply saved to the database as a string.

Comment: Are you sure? I may be able to help you if you do not insist, but if you do, you might lose people's help. By the way, an entire YAML format is a string.

Comment: yeah... that does look like yaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, its not perfect, but do the trick.

```
s = "---\n- :@error: 'Invalid phone number format: ''''.  Please check that your format  for\n    phone number is correct.'\n- :@error: 'Invalid id was sent: '\n- :@error: 'Invalid date format: '\n"
# scan will get the strings between quotes that are not themselves quotes
# it returns an array of arrays
# flatten will make it a single array
# gsub then strip will normalize the results.
msgs = s.scan(/'([^']+)'/).map{ |(msg)| msg.gsub(/(\.|\s+)/, ' ').strip }

#["Invalid phone number format:", 
# "Please check that your format for phone number is correct", 
# "Invalid id was sent:", 
# "Invalid date format:"]
```

Comment: You could eliminate `flatten` by changing the expression for the block variable to `|(msg)|`.

Answer (score 1):

Try splitting your string where it says `@error`.

```
error_messages = string.split('@error')
error_messages.each {|e| p e.gsub(/[\n:'-]/, '').strip}
```

This returns the following

```
"Invalid phone number format .  Please check that your format for    phone number is correct."
"Invalid id was sent"
"Invalid date format"
```

I've got this pretty close, I just need to play with this and see if I can edit the whitespace.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be the best solution that works for me. However I get an empty string first before the error messages. Is there a way to get rid of that? Speculating, but could it be coming from the `"---\n- :` at the start of the string?

Comment: Yes, that's a result of the newline. I'm removing the newline character and some special characters from every line.

Answer (score 1):

This is a YAML string, so treat it as such. Your life will be easier:

```
require 'yaml'

str = "---\n- :@error: 'Invalid phone number format: ''''.  Please check that your format  for\n    phone number is correct.'\n- :@error: 'Invalid id was sent: '\n- :@error: 'Invalid date format: '\n"

error = YAML.load(str)
error = YAML.load(str)
# => [{:@error=>
#       "Invalid phone number format: ''.  Please check that your format  for phone number is correct."},
#     {:@error=>"Invalid id was sent: "},
#     {:@error=>"Invalid date format: "}]
```

We can see it's an array of errors now. Looking at the first one:

```
error[0] # => {:@error=>"Invalid phone number format: ''.  Please check that your format  for phone number is correct."}
```

Accessing the error is easily done now:

```
error[0][:@error] # => "Invalid phone number format: ''.  Please check that your format  for phone number is correct."
```

Comment: It's interesting that no one seemed to notice that it was a YAML string until you posted your answer, roughly three hours after the question went up. I don't know YAML, but I'd think most members who write Ruby for a living do. This seems like it's certainly the way to go.

Comment: @CarySwoveland See my comment to the question. I posted that comment 46 seconds after the question post. Two other people thought the same thing before this answer was posted. However, unlike the poster of this answer, we three respected what the OP wrote back in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

`your_string.scan(/@error: '(.*): ?'/)` will return array of errors messages.

Comment: this misses "Please check that your format for phone number is correct."

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that each error message (other than `"---\n"` at the beginning) begins with a hyphen and ends with a newline. If so, you can extract them as follows:

```
str = "---\n- :@error: 'Invalid phone number format: ''''.  Please check that your format  for\n    phone number is correct.'\n- :@error: 'Invalid id was sent: '\n- :@error: 'Invalid date format: '\n"

str.scan(/-.*?\n(?=-|$)/m)[1..-1]
  #=> ["- :@error: 'Invalid phone number format: ''''.  Please check that your format  for\n    phone number is correct.'\n",
  #    "- :@error: 'Invalid id was sent: '\n",
  #    "- :@error: 'Invalid date format: '\n"]
```

Notes:

- `[1..-1]` discards the initial match `"---\n"`.
- the multiline modifier `/m` is necessary because each error message may contain newlines.
- `?` in `.*?` makes `.*` lazy. Without it, an array containing one element, the entire string, is returned by `str.scan(/-.*\n(?=-|$)/m)`, so the following `[1..-1]` returns an empty array.
- the positive lookahead `(?=-|$)/m)` ensures that the end of the error message is immediately followed by a hyphen or the end of the string.